# What difference between numbers 3 and 0x03 and how to check this diff

Tags: php, numbers, int, hex

I have two constants with different numbers. But i don't understand how to check they difference between them.

I tried use functions `hexdec`, `dechex`, `bin2hex` and other

```php
const FIRST = 3;
const SECOND = 0x03;
```

I need short and pretty fast condition to check the difference

Comment: `FIRST - SECOND === 0`. They're same.

Comment: This values are exactly the same.

Comment: If you mean the value difference between them, PHP will juggle between binary (0b11), octal (03), decimal (3) and hexadecimal (0x03) just fine with normal operators (e.g. 0x03 + 3 === 6; 3 - 0x03 === 0;)